# Python-xml: Verify child element exist for every parent instance

Tags: python, xml, parsing, tags, get-childitem

I am new to python so I appreciate your help. I have an xml code similar to

```
  <ticket >
    <device name="device1"/>
    <detail>
      <name>customer1</name>
      <ip>11.12.13.4/32</ip>
      <blob gid="20" lid="10"/>
    </detail>
    <classification>C1</classification>
  </ticket>

  <ticket >
    <device name="device2"/>
    <detail>
      <name>customer2</name>
    </detail>
    <classification>C2</classification>
  </ticket>
```

What I need is to check every instance of  to verify whether or not the tag  exists in every `<detail>` parent. If it exists then print the value and if not then print the msg `"no ip record"`.

The output should be something like this:

```
name= customer1
ip= 11.12.13.4/32

name=customer2
ip= No ip record.
```

How I can get this in python?

Comment: Have a look at this - http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution using [xml.etree.ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) from the standard library:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


data = """
<root>
<ticket >
    <device name="device1"/>
    <detail>
      <name>customer1</name>
      <ip>11.12.13.4/32</ip>
      <blob gid="20" lid="10"/>
    </detail>
    <classification>C1</classification>
  </ticket>

  <ticket >
    <device name="device2"/>
    <detail>
      <name>customer2</name>
    </detail>
    <classification>C2</classification>
  </ticket>
</root>"""

tree = ET.fromstring(data)
for ticket in tree.findall('.//ticket'):
    name = ticket.find('.//name').text
    ip = ticket.find('.//ip')
    ip = ip.text if ip is not None else 'No ip record'
    print "name={name}, ip={ip}".format(name=name, ip=ip)
```

prints:

```
name=customer1, ip=11.12.13.4/32
name=customer2, ip=No ip record
```